# Как получить значения Rect Transform из кода?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как получить значения отсюда из кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я прочитал в документации про компонент Rect Transform, но не понял, какие значения из api соответствуют значениям в инспекторе. Обычно атрибут из кода соответствует названиям в инспекторе, и я могу интуитивно понятно их использовать, но по Rect Transform VS не даёт подсказок по типу PosX или Width. Есть rect и sizeDelta, но я НЕ ПОНЯЛ как они соотносятся со значениями в инспекторе.
Пожалуйста, не надо писать что в документации про это написано. Я уже писал, что не понял того что там написано и прошу объяснить это здесь.

Comment: `RectTransfomr t = transform as RectTransform;`

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробная документация, вся нужное в первой табличке : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

Так же если вам станет не понятно где взять позицию, размер итд.
То вам нужен rect(RectTransform.rect), он вернёт вам обычный Transform как на обычных объектах.

Так же не забывайте что вам нужно сделать GetComponent. И обращаться к той переменной, в которую вы записали его.

Comment: Специально в вопросе указал что я НЕ понял то что написано в документации. Я конечно уже разобрался с этим вопросом, но можно в следующий раз повнимательнее быть.

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков Так я вам расписал, что скоро всего вам нужен rect и то что он содержит обічний трансформ. Сказал что надо сделать GetComponent.